# Messed-up div IDs for ajax-modified form field

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I want to change, using Ajax, some attributes to `field2` (a select widget) when `field1` changes:

In mymodule.module:

```
function mymodule_form_NODETYPE_FORM_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['filed1']["widget"]['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'on_filed1_change',
        'wrapper' => 'edit-field-filed2-wrapper', 
        'event' => 'change',
        'method' => 'replace',
    );
}

function on_filed1_change(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)  {
    $form['field2'] = $modified_field2;
    return $form['field2'];
}
```

**This works only the first time.**

I found out the following id's have been changed with **additional trailing random numbers**:

- `edit-field-field2-wrapper--GCPg2vSCav0` for `field2` wrapper `<div>`
- `edit-field-field2--EXhOuuWQld8` for `field2` `<select>` element

Since the original Ajax wrapper `edit-field-field2-wrapper` no longer exists, no further modifications to `field2` are possible.

Why does this happen? And how can I prevent this from happening, or use the new IDs as wrapper in the Ajax call?

I'm using 8.6.0-dev.

Comment: It increments to make them unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function mymodule_form_NODETYPE_FORM_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['field2']['#attributes']['id'] = 'my_dom_id_for_elem2';
    // or if it doesn't work properly you can wrap the element
    // $form['field2']['#prefix'] = '<div id="my_dom_id_for_elem2">';
    // $form['field2']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['filed1']["widget"]['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'on_filed1_change',
        'wrapper' => 'my_dom_id_for_elem2', 
        'event' => 'change',
        'method' => 'replace',
    ); }

function on_filed1_change(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // This line is not necessary, at this time $form['field2']
    // has already been modified and you can just return the form element itself, it will be used as response.data by javascript.
    //$form['field2'] = $modified_field2;
    return $form['field2'];
```

}

Comment: @kladrin This works fine for me for textfield elements, but for dropdown select lists, it changes the top level select Id, but all ID's on its select elements still have their ID's incrementing, and there are too many to manually set ID's for

Answer (score 2):

Drupal changes DOM IDs on every submit.
You can, however, fix them by adding an attribute specification to your element:

```
$form['field2']['#attributes']['id'] = 'my_dom_id_for_elem2';
```

and then use **my_dom_id_for_elem2** as your wrapper property.

Comment: Where exactly should this line of code be placed?

Comment: I added a new answer based on your code, try that solution and read the comments, you can either add the ID attribute or wrap the element with a div, I prefer the latter :)

Comment: this does not work for subforms where the upper field is not cardinality 1, u would get the same id multiple times